# Blender 2.8: Pink from Missing Textures After an Import

Tags: texturing, import, image, texture-coordinates

I import various types of models into Blender 2.8.  Sometimes, the textures show up as pink, while others appear fine.  I understand that both the importers and exporters for Blender will generally not cover all textures.  For me, these include mainly .jpg and .png images.  Now, if the model formats include OBJ or glTF, then I can possibly do something, but if not, then I can't.  I would like to point Blender 2.8 as to the texture's location and name.  It seems to me that texture placement is already mapped on the mesh, but simply, the file name is wrong.

***How should I approach this?***

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the menu File->External Data->Find Missing Files and point to the folder where the texture may be? Sometimes the texture file location points to a different folder then the actual model.

Comment: Yes.  I have tried this.  It says:  **Could not find 'Map #some_number' in 'some_folder'.**  It seems that the file name for a texture is not taken into account during the import when the importer itself skips a texture, so a random number, beginning with "Map #", gets assigned.